# The js for-loop code is printed before it is called

Tags: javascript, html, function, for-loop, undefined

I'm a new Javascript coder and this is my first question here.

I have the following code that:

1. takes each value from the variable named celsius
2. takes that value to the function named calculate and convert it into
   fahrenheit.
3. the value of the fahrenheit is taken back to the first
   function and then printed to the first function

```css
function calculate() {  
    var celsius = [12, 45, 99, -40];
    
    for (i=0 ; i<celsius.length; i++) {
        document.write("The value is " + celsius[i] + " and is equal to " + count(celsius[i]) + "<br>")
    }
}

function count(num) {
    var degfarhen = 9/5 * parseFloat(num) + 32;
    degfarhen = degfarhen.toFixed(1);
    document.write(degfarhen)
}
```

but this happens

```css
53.6The value is 12 and is equal to undefined
113.0The value is 45 and is equal to undefined
210.2The value is 99 and is equal to undefined
-40.0The value is -40 and is equal to undefined
```

The value of fahrenheit is printed before the sentence and where it actually have to be printed stays undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the function `count` you are calling `document.write()` which will immediately write to the document.

Because this is called inside another `document.write` (in the for loop), the inner one will write before the outer one. You're seeing "undefined" because the function isn't returning a value.

What you need to do is to `return degfarhen` at the end of `count` instead of document.write-ing it..

```
function count(num) {
  // calculation remains the same
  return degfarhen; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `document.write(degfarhen)` to `return degfarhen;`

Comment: Thangs ....... but what the difference between document.write and return... i mean why they behave differently in my code.... (document.write in the beginning and return at the required place?)

Comment: The document.write('text portion') function simply outputs the string, in this case 'text portion' to the document, while return will return the calculated value to the caller, which is the end of your string.